# Accessing phone gallery and camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How to access Phone gallery and camera in windows phone7 through code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are Launchers and Choosers which allow you to call these options and they also allow you to call other things such as map,sms compose,search etc.

here is an example of one (camera)

- Creating Object

`CameraCaptureTask cvt = new CameraCaptureTask();`

- Registering event

`cvt.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cv_Completed);`

`cvt.Show();`

- Creating callback method

`private void cv_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult r)`
       `{//Your Code Here
        }`

also read here - [MSDN- Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769556%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You want to see many good samples in the good [Nokia Developer Windows Phone Website](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Portal%3aWindows_Phone_Multimedia). They're good tutoriel with many samples.